# Implementation of annotated decision (probability) trees in R?

Tags: r, tree, probability

I'm wondering how to implement annotated decision trees or probability trees in R, like in this picture (it's supposed to illustrate whether or not to buy a ticket, which is cheaper if you make it in time. You have a 60 % chance of making it in time, in which case the ticket is $200. If you don't make it in time, you'll lose the $200, and you'll have to buy a later ticket, which is $400. If you just buy the late ticket, it's $400):

[image]

The argument is as follows: You have a 60 % chance of spending $200 and a 40 % chance of spending $600, which adds up as 0.6 * $200 + 0.4 * $600 = $360, whereas if you just buy the more expensive ticket, you pay $400. So you should choose the cheaper one.

Is there an R package for that kind of annotated decision trees or probability trees? Or any good ideas how to implement it?

Thanks,
Signe

Comment: check this link : http://www.harrysurden.com/wordpress/archives/292

Comment: it works for me, but just type "R probability tree" in your browser and you will have a lot of links

Comment: It also worked for me the fourth time I clicked on it, so I deleted my comment again. However, I'd still need to get the weighted sums along the branches and pick the optimal one, which this post doesn't really say anything about.